# How do I check whether a class has children classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a function that takes a class as a parameter and returns `True` or `False` depending on the existence of its children classes? Can it be possible in principle?

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

has_children(A)  # should return True
has_children(B)  # should return False
```

I would like to know a solution without access to `globals()`, `locals()`, `vars()`.

Comment: Just for references, I have just posted a solution working with old style Python 2 classes (no __subclasses__ method available)  under the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893520/3545273)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `__subclasses__` method:

```
def has_children(cls):
    return bool(cls.__subclasses__())
```

This method is only defined for "new-style" classes (inherit from `object` in Python 2, default in Python 3).

Comment: Thanks, it worked.